# Unable to verify email while using simple JWT in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

The register and login sections are functioning properly in my django application. When someone registers he receives a confirmation email, but on clicking the email confirmation link the account is not verified. I'm using try and except, it's the except that is being executed each time and try never executes.

```
models.py

username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
  serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            key = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
            user = User.objects.get(id=key['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()
            return Response({'email': 'Your email has been activated'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'token not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Please I want to know why the the code in the `try` section never gets executed even when the token is intact and has not expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `key = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])`